# StyleGan2 ADA PyTorch Output Image Resolution Assertion Error

Tags: python, pytorch, stylegan

I am trying to produce an image using StyleGan2.

Executing this cell:

```
!python train.py --gpus=1 --cfg=$config --metrics=None --outdir=./results --data=$dataset_path --snap=$snapshot_count --resume=$resume_from --augpipe=$augs --initstrength=$aug_strength --gamma=$gamma_value --mirror=$mirror_x --mirrory=False --nkimg=$train_count
```

outputs the following:

```
Output directory:   ./results/00001-datasets-mirror-11gb-gpu-gamma50-bg-resumecustom
Training data:      /content/datasets.zip
Training duration:  25000 kimg
Number of GPUs:     1
Number of images:   608
Image resolution:   600
Conditional model:  False
Dataset x-flips:    True

Creating output directory...
Launching processes...
Loading training set...

Num images:  1216
Image shape: [3, 600, 600]
Label shape: [0]
```

then gives me the assertion error down below:

```
assert img_resolution >= 4 and img_resolution & (img_resolution - 1) == 0
Assertion Error:
```

I checked the [source](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2-ada-pytorch/blob/main/training/networks.py#:%7E:text=assert%20img_resolution%20%3E%3D%204%20and%20img_resolution%20%26%20(img_resolution%20-%201)%20%3D%3D%200) of the error.
But to be fair I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found:
The issue is the input dimension of the image must be at least `[3, 1024, 1024]` mine was `[3, 600, 600]`